# DotNetNuke Bug in IE10

Tags: editor, dotnetnuke

So I am using DotNetNuke 7 and when I log onto my site to develop, I go into Edit Mode and start to edit a module.

Once the edit screen shows up (the little text area that looks like a mini version of MS Word) I can type and everything is fine.

However when that little screen loses focus from the mouse the editing area "greys-out" but I can still type in it.

I want to know how to fix this so that the editing screen does NOT do this as it is very confusing to potential customers.

Does anyone know what to do to fix this issue?

(sorry if this is not descriptive enough, if anyone has problems understanding I will try to add more explicit wording)

Answer (score 0):

There have been reports of other oddities in IE10.

One thing you could try is adding a meta tag to force IE into IE9 mode.